# fltk cmake ubuntu link error

Tags: ubuntu, linker, cmake, fltk

I am trying to compile a simple FLTK program but it always brings a link error. When I build with this command, it works

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include \
    -I/usr/include/freetype2 \
    -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE \
    -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE \
    -D_THREAD_SAFE \
    -D_REENTRANT \
    -o 'ex01' './ex01.cxx' /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a \
    -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig \
    -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11
```

when I try cmake with these lines:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.6.1)
PROJECT(ex01)
FIND_PACKAGE(FLTK REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenGL REQUIRED)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(ex01 ex01.cxx)
TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(ex01 PUBLIC ${FLTK_INCLUDE_DIR} ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(ex01 ${FLTK_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
```

I get this error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable ex01
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfltk.a(Fl_x.o): undefined  reference to symbol 'dlsym@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing    from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [ex01] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ex01.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My system has Ubuntu 14 and cmake 3.6.1. Any suggestion? is there a way to add the previous g++ options to the CMakeLists.txt file?
Many thanks!
Ibraheem

Comment: You may also have forgotten to add the preprocessor defines. Check that with a verbose run of cmake/make to see the actual compiler invocations. You'll need [`target_compile_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/target_compile_definitions.html) for specifying the defines.

Comment: Thanks again.  target_compile_def‌initions() needs micros. I used TARGET_COMPILE_OPTIONS(ex01 PUBLIC -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11 )
 instead​ but still get the same error

Comment: `target_compile_definitions` and `target_compile_options` are two entirely different things. I've update my answer. All these `-l...` you are manually adding should already be covered by `${FLTK_LIBRARIES}` and `${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}`.

Comment: Tried it, still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I got help here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fltkgeneral/GWlW6KiYnKM
Now it works :) .
I had to: 1- download and build the last version of fltk using cmake. 2-change CMakeLists.txt to be like this:
   

    `CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.6) 
    PROJECT(ex01) 
    FIND_PACKAGE(FLTK REQUIRED NO_MODULE)  # must use "NO_MODULE" 
    include_directories(${FLTK_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 
    link_directories(${FLTK_LIBRARY_DIRS}) 
    add_definitions(${FLTK_DEFINITIONS})

    ADD_EXECUTABLE( ex01 ex01.cxx ) 
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( ex01 fltk ) # notice fltk here`

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu16 with fltk version 1.3.4 what a lifesaver I've been hitting my head against the wall all night with this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that CMake files shipped with Ubuntu 14 doesn't specify all needed linker flags for the static FLTK library.

The output of `fltk-config --ldstaticflags` is:

```
... -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lfontconfig -lXinerama -ldl -lm -lX11
```

While `/usr/lib/fltk/FLTKLibraries-noconfig.cmake` line 18 only contains:

```
-lXft;-lfontconfig;-lXinerama;-lX11;-lm
```

The solution is to link `Xext` and `dl` libs manually. The full code is:

```
find_package(FLTK REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
include(${FLTK_USE_FILE})
target_link_libraries(app fltk Xext dl)
```

Alternatively, you can also link to shared libraries:

```
target_link_libraries(app fltk_SHARED)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the include directories for the dependent libraries *FLTK* and *OpenGL*. The *Find* modules provide these variables.

Use [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/target_include_directories.html):

```
target_include_directories(ex01
                           PUBLIC ${FLTK_INCLUDE_DIR}
                                  ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

---

*Edit*:
In addition, you are missing the preprocessor definitions

```
-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE
-D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
-D_THREAD_SAFE
-D_REENTRANT
```

You need to define them for your executable via [`target_compile_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/target_compile_definitions.html):

```
target_compile_definitions(ex01
                           PUBLIC _LARGEFILE_SOURCE
                                  _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
                                  _THREAD_SAFE
                                  _REENTRANT)
```

---

For any further CMake debugging use [`CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEILFE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/variable/CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE.html) to let `make` print out the compiler invocations. That will tell you what else is missing.

---

*Side note: Do you really need to require CMake 2.6? As long as don't you have to support systems which don't provide a recent CMake, I'd recommend requiring at least CMake version 3.0.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your solution but now I get this error: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES):
  target_include_directories called with invalid arguments.

Comment: Sorry, screwed up the syntax. Fixed it. Anyway, you should read that documentation!

Comment: Thanks again, I tried the new syntax but now back again to the previous error. I updated the contents in the question.